# Get file count from external website

Tags: php, javascript, coldfusion

Is there any type of javascript, coldfusion, php, etc that can recursively get all the public files of an external website for display/count?

Comment: Do you have access to the file system, or are you talking about doing it through HTTP requests?

Comment: I think you could use `wget --spider|wc -l` for this, but not able to test it out right now.

Comment: @AJ - awesome. I didn't know wget could do this but I'm sure as hell going to try it now

Comment: Via http request.  AJ, is that command for Apache?

Comment: wget can often return `Remote file exists and could contain further links, but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and if it was possible, it would be a security flaw that would quickly be patched. Surely you wouldn't want others the same access to your server.

May I read your .htaaccess please?  No sir, you may not.

=)

Answer (score 1):

Only if the directory structure is exposed, say, through Apache's "directory does not have an index page". In that case, you can use an XML parser and get the href's of all of the `<a>` tags and recurse that way.

In most cases, though, you'll not be able to find an exposed directory. In such a case, you might have difficulty determining the server type and getting the file structure is hopeless.